# Latex landscape rotates one of two figures

Tags: graphics, rotating, landscape

I was trying to put two figures with separate captions (no subfigures) with following code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth]{figure1}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth]{figure1}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}
```

and what happened after using `pdflatex`is both pages were horizontal/landscape but only figure1 was in proper orientation and the other figure on the second page was rotated by 90 degrees.
So I rewrote my code to:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth]{figure1}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth]{figure1}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}
```

to give separate `landscape` environments for my figures and everything was fine, meaning I had two landscape pages with my figures in proper orientation.
Could you explain to me why it works this way, please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

- Figures are meant to float. You can not put them into `landscape` environments, as those are for parts of the text. (I mean, the figure will not necessarily be printed where they appear in the source code.)
- You should not use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside a figure, but rather `\centering` as the former add vertical space.
- In case you don't want the figures to float, do not use the `figure` environment, but just include them with `\includegraphics`.

The following code should solve your problem, if I understood you correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{foo \label{fig1}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{bar \label{fig2}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```